# ubuntu server cpu utilisation increasing very quickly after installing ELK

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, cpu-usage, elk

I installed elasticsearch logstash and kibana in the ubuntu server. Before I starting these services the CPU utilization is less than 5% and after starting these services in the next minute the CPU utilization crossing 85%. I don't know why it is happening. Can anyone help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your Logstash configuration? Also can you run `top` and share the results?

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your question to give you a specific answer, but i will point out few possible scenarios and how to deal with them.

1. Did you wait long enough? sometimes there is a warmpup which is consuming higher CPU until all services are registered and finish to boot. if you have a fairly small machine it might consume higher CPU and take longer to finish.
2. folder write permissions. if any of the components of the ELK fails due to restricted access on needed directories either for logging, creating sub folders for sinceDB files or more it can cause it to go into an infinity loop and try again and again while it is consuming high CPU.
3. connection issues. ES should be the first component to start, if it fails, Kibana and Logstash will go and try to connect to the ES again and again until successful connection- which can cause high CPU.
4. bad logstash configuration. if logstash fails to read the file from the configurations or if you have a bad parsing, excessive parsing for example- your first "match" in the filter part will include the least common option it might consume high CPU.

For further investigation:

1. I suggest you to not start all of them together. start ES first. if everything goes well start Kibana and lastly start Logstash.
2. check the logs of all the ELK components to find error messages, failures, etc.
3. for a better answer I will need the yaml of all 3 components (ES, Kibana, Logstash)
4. I will need the logstash configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Would recommend you to analyse the CPU cycles consumed by each of the elasticsearch, logstash and kibana process.
2. Check specifically which process among the above is consuming the most memory/cpu via top command for example.
3. Start only ES first and allow it to settle and the node to be started completely before starting kibana and may be logstash after that.
4. Send me the logs for each and I can assist if there are any errors.